# Rebuilding the array of dictionaries into array of hierarchical trees

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have followed the suggestion from Scott Sauer, and have used the solution from this post but tried to adapt to take into account the topics object that is already present.

The original post is here
[Invert data structure while deduplicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813288/invert-data-structure-while-deduplicating)

I have modified the function, but now I am getting duplicates in the deepest dictionary, I would appreciate if anyone could point out what am I doing wrong?

```js
const initObject = [
  { 
    id: 5,
    topics: [{
      id: 7,
      topics: [
        {id:9, topics:[]}
      ]
    }],
    parent: {
     id: 10,
     parent: {
       id: 15,
       parent: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    topics: [
        {id:9, topics:[]}
    ],
    parent: {
     id: 5,
     parent: {
       id: 10,
       parent: {
         id: 15,
         parent: null
       }
      }
    }
  }
]

function reverseGraphAll(data) {
    const rootTopics = [];
    const map = new Map([[undefined, rootTopics]]);
    
    function upward({id, parent, topics}) {
        if (map.has(id)) return map.get(id);
        let topicsNew = topics ? topics : [];
        map.set(id, topicsNew);
        (parent ? upward(parent) : rootTopics).push({id, topicsNew});
        return topicsNew;
    }
    
    data.forEach(upward);
    return rootTopics;
}

const result = reverseGraphAll(initObject);
console.log("Total", result);
```

Comment: Why would you expect someone to do your job here?

Comment: @zerdox, good point and I don't expect anyone to do the job, i am a beginner in coding and just need some help with certain tasks.

Comment: You need to post your attempt at least. Have you tried to code the solution? What you ended up with? Maybe try to put it into playground and post here?

Comment: I have tried multiple things, for example there is a similar post on stack, this one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106299/reverse-object-hierarchy

Comment: But the challenge there is that it only reverses the hierarchy, so i would end up with array of reversed hierarchies, and my next try would be to use Map to essentially deduplicate the array of dictionaries. I am trying more options as we speak, but just thought maybe someone much smarter than me could help

Comment: Isn't this essentially the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74813288/1243641) you asked the other day?  Yes, the cleanup is nice, but you accepted trincot's answer to that one; does it not apply here?  What am I missing?

Comment: @ScottSauyet good point, its indeed similar but i couod not modify it to essentialy check if topics array is present then add to the array otherwise create empty array. because write now the lowest topics array becomes empty...

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have update my question with my attempt at reusing the solution from previous post but taking into account the presence of topics array, though I am getting duplicates in the deepest nested dictionary. Any chance you could pinpoint the issue?

Comment: About the input structure: this now has both upward and downward information. This makes that the second entry of your top level array adds *nothing* new to what is already known from the first array entry. Can you clarify why you start with such a structure, and could you give a less trivial example (your graph is essentially a single path)?

Comment: Thanks @trincot for your question. Basically I am using strapi and next js building a simple web app. There we have a topic hierarchy, with essentially topics having child topics, belonging to higher level topics. When I query strapi entity service for those topics, i get essentially an array of dictionaries representing those topics that a user has access to (a user can access multiple topics). Each topic has questions, user should be able to access those questions, but also be able to see to which higher level topics a specific topic belongs to. I hope this provides a bit more explanation

Comment: Let me know if this is clearer, the reason for the above is that it could be that a user is wrongly assigned to a topic and the sub-topic, in which case strapi would actually return both topics, since its a self-referential table. While this is an edge case for me, its something I need to take care of

Comment: Posted an answer. It would still be nice if you could provide a less trivial example of input and corresponding expected output, as the graph you have currently represented is a single path.

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot, this worked like a charm. You are correct though it will always be single path, meaning that each dictionary in the main array will contain nested topics, with nested reference to parents just for information purposes, since each topic also contains questions, but for the parents I never need to get the questions. I will perform further tests with different use cases and share my further feedback afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate (recursively) the `topics` properties, so to mark them in the `map` too, thus registering where each of those child nodes is positioned in the final hierarchy:

```js
function reverseGraphAll(data) {
    const rootTopics = [];
    const nodeMap = new Map([[undefined, { topics: rootTopics }]]);
    const expanded = new Set;
    
    function upward({id, parent}) {
        if (nodeMap.has(id)) return nodeMap.get(id);
        const node = {id, topics: []};
        nodeMap.set(id, node);
        upward(Object(parent)).topics.push(node);
        return node;
    }
    
    function expand({id, topics}) {
        if (expanded.has(id)) return;
        expanded.add(id);
        nodeMap.get(id).topics = topics;
        for (const topic of topics) {
            nodeMap.set(topic.id, topic);
            expand(topic);
        }
    }
    
    data.forEach(node => (upward(node), expand(node)));
    return rootTopics;
}

const initObject = [{id: 5,topics: [{id: 7,topics: [{id:9, topics:[]}]}],parent: {id: 10,parent: {id: 15,parent: null}}},{id: 7,topics: [{id:9, topics:[]}],parent: {id: 5,parent: {id: 10,parent: {id: 15,parent: null}}}}];
const result = reverseGraphAll(initObject);
console.log(result);
```